# How to create a dynamic chart in access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, diagram, diagrams

I have one table that is an income distribution. It contains the share of individuals within each quintile. In another table that is created through input via form the income of a indivudal is contained and the corresponding quintile. Now in a form following that of the one that asks the income I would like to display a graph with the income distribution were the quintile of the individual just asked is contained.

I manage to create the graph of the income distribution but how do I include the indivudals quintile?

edit: 
Unfortionately I can't add the the real data because it is derived from a panel used under license. However I can give you a basic idea of how the tables look:

Table Lorenz Curve (i.e. the income distribution) 
    ID   Share   quintile
    1     0,2        1
    2     0,35       2
    3     0,4        3
    .      .         .
    .      .         .
 
    .      .         .

Table Collected data
    ID    Income    Quintile   Age   Sex   ...
    1     1300      2          26    1

Comment: Add some sample data please.

Comment: Apparently there is a way to do this via Excel:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/93dfe939-ceb1-452f-8806-3c24a8a809a6/access-2010-charts-not-as-feature-rich-as-excel

Unfortionately my VBA skills are not sufficient for that.